# Can't remove text-decoration from anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor, text-decorations

I can't remove `text-decoration` from my web and I have tried in many attempts to solve it. Nothing worked.
The text-decoration in fact is gone, but, I realized that when I click on my link (anchor tag), and then I go back in the browser, the text-decoration appears again. Why does this happen? is it a bug or should I add more CSS to my code to fix this? and how could I solve this?

Reference of what I tried:

```css
  /*
  a > div p {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white;
  }

  a:link > div p {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white;
  }

  .izquierda a > div p {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: white;
  } 
  */

  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    /*color: white;*/
  }
```

```html
   <div class="opciones">
          <!-- OPCIONES DIVIDIDAS A LA IZQUIERDA -->
          <div class="izquierda">
            <a class="anchor" href="/editar_perfil.html">
              <div class="editar-perfil">
                <img
                  src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"
                  alt="Icono de Editar Perfil"
                  title="Puedes editar la biografía e imagen de tu perfil."
                />
                <p>Editar Perfil</p>
              </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Apparently, in the snippet the text-decoration doesn't appear but in my browser it remains (I am using Opera GX). And happens what I explained.
[This is what appears. The text-decoration is still there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFks.png)

**PD: Apparently, the text-decoration in fact is gone, but, I realized that when I click on my link (anchor tag), and then I go back in the browser, the text-decoration appears again. Why does this happen? and how could I solve this?**

Comment: ````text-decoration: none```` removes the underline from the text inside the ````<a>````, and this appears to have worked correctly in your example. The text is not underlined.

Comment: The snippet in your post shows text without any decoration.

Comment: I don't see any text decoration.

Comment: Apparently, the text-decoration in fact is gone, but, I realized that when I click on my link (anchor tag), and then I go back in the browser to the initial page the text-decoration appears again. Why does this happen? and how could I solve this? Is it a bug?

Comment: I made an update to explain it better, hopefully I explained it correctly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: setting `a {text-decoration: none !important;}` should remove all text decoration unless there is a style below that for `a` tag which sets the text decoration back to default?

Comment: the best way to debug it is to inspect that `<a>` element and see which style rule causes the `text-decoration`. It could also be that the css file is cached so you might wanna hard reload `ctrl+shift+r` on your browser